# Where are Django Admin Site's static media files? and How to configure?

Tags: python, django

So far, I have been using a stable release of django: 1.3, and my settings.py looked like this (for admin site):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

I just switched to development version, and once I ran the server, got the following warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: The ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX setting has been removed; use STATIC_URL instead.
 "use STATIC_URL instead.", DeprecationWarning)
```

AND, my admin site looks different now (without all the css, javascript, etc).

I tried changing the static url to different possibilities, and got rid of admin media prefix altogether, but the original look of admin site was not retrieved.

Can someone tell me how to configure this?

Comment: Post the location of your static files

Comment: I guess you know that using a development version of software may have bugs and may not be fully documented. Should you join django developers list to post your questions?

Comment: While this would be true for must software, Django dev version tend to be incredibly stable and well documented (given their status of course). E.G: the answer of this question is in the documentation. This is why I'm +1 this: while it's a legitimate question, the OP didn't loop very far since the answer is the first link if you type 'static files' in the django doc search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the next Django version, [static files handling](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) behave like the old django-staticfiles app:

- to ensure that you got all static files from all apps, convention is put each app static file in a subdir called 'static'
- on dev, everything is served automatically by the dev server
- on prod, everything is statically served from one directory with your HTTP prod server. To fill this directory, use `./manage.py collectstatic`

So you don't need `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` because the admin static files will be either served automatically during dev, or collected automatically by `collectstatic` during prod.

`STATIC_URL` should match the URL you will serve the static content, ALL of it, in prod. `STATIC_ROOT` should be the absolute path to the directory where you want the static files to be copied by `collectstatic`.